# VBScript not working with localhost but with ip address

Tags: vbscript, https, internet-explorer-9

```
function printTransactionDetails(htmlString)

    'set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
    'msgbox objShell
    Const OLECMDID_SAVE = 3
    Const OLECMDID_SAVEAS = 4
    Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6 
    Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2 
    Const PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2
        MsgBox ("amogh0")   
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        'Set ie = new InternetExplorer
        MsgBox ("amogh1")
        'navigate to blank page so that the document object is available
        ie.navigate "about:blank"
        ie.visible=0
        'msgbox ie.document.body.innerHTML
        ie.document.body.style.margin = 20 
        ie.document.body.innerHTML=htmlString
        'msgbox ie.document.body.innerHTML
        ie.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION
        'Quit IE
        ie.quit
end function
```

I have a JSP in which i have the above code .. it is used to print. 
CreateObject("InternertExplorer.Application") is throwing an error when i use https: // loclhost:8444/MyApp while it works when i use https://10.192.51.xx:8444/MyApp

Comment: It's unlikely that `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` is raising the error, since there is no `https://loclhost:8444/MyApp` in that line. Please show the *exact* error message you're getting (error number, description and line number).

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere you have accessed the hostname or the IP address in your above code. If it is working with your IP and not with the host name, then I can imagine only below two things that could have gone wrong.

1. DNS mapping with IP Address.
2. Incorrectly spelled hostname. From your description, it looks like you have written "localhost" as "loclhost"

Please provide the exact code which is throwing an error.